# Group by ALL days in a range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a requirement to have results returned from a query for every day in a range, even if the database has no results.

Is there some groupBy trick I can do for this, or will I have to merge my results into a pre-generated empty results list?

Edit:
All I have so far is a query to get the aggregate results per day (that there are results) (slightly modified to remove company data so I hope it still makes sense!)

```
 public List<MetricsResult> GetReport(DateTime toDate, DateTime fromDate)
    {
        var results =
            context.Histories.Where(
                history => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(history.Sent) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fromDate) &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(history.Sent) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(toDate)))
                .GroupBy(h => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(h.Sent))
                .Select(histories => new MetricsResult
                {
                    Sent = histories.Count(f => f.Sent != null),
                    Unsubscribed = histories.Count(f => f.Unsubscribed.HasValue),
                    Day = histories.Key
                });

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: sounds like you have to merge.  There are tricks you can do on the SQL side but you don't have access to the sql if you are using entity-framework.

Comment: if you post what  you have so far there may be some linq code that will make this easy.

Comment: more of a left join then group by trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like below, using linq to objects

```
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, (toDate - fromDate).TotalDays)
    .Select(i => fromDate.Date.AddDays(i));
```

you'll get each of the days in your range.

Then if you get your results, and instead do,

```
var lookup = results.ToDictionary(mr => mr.Day, mr);
```

then you can do,

```
var newResults = days.Select(day =>
    {
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(day))
        {
            return lookup[day];
        }
        else
        {
            return new MetricsResult
                {
                    Day = day
                };  
        }
    }).ToList();
```

and avoid another trip to your database.

---

If you need the result to be `IQueryable` thats a different proposition, but since I saw the `ToList()` in your code this is a better choice.

Comment: very nice answer Jodrell!  (the days query was exactly what I was thinking of when I said "linq code that would make this easy")